# django makemigrations no longer detects changes (1.8+)

Tags: django

If I make a change to a model in django it no longer picks up changes with

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I did previously delete the database (postgres) via dropdb, and recreated it with createdb. I then deleted the migrations from the apps migrations folder.  Before doing this makemigrations did work ok for that app.

What is the best way to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreate the migrations folder with an `__init__.py` file. A shortcut for this is to run `python manage.py makemigrations <app_label>`. The app label here is important, otherwise it will treat your app as an unmigrated app and it won't  create any migrations.

Comment: Thanks and here you mean replace <app_label> with the particular app in question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

Or, just add `__init__.py` file on each migrations folder.